# Grey dot on scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, visual-studio-2017

What is the grey dot on scrollbar in Visual Studio 2017?

[image: grey dot on scrollbar]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Code Suggestions

A scenario I ran into was forgetting to capitalize my method.

Another suggestion I saw was a recommendation for improving how I initialized a collection.

When I select the line with the grey mark I can then try quick actions to view suggestions.

Comment: how to hide those grey dots?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2017, it corresponds with Error List - Messages.
Usually it is a Naming rule violation:(definition), but, it could be any Message.
[Error List Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks.

One of several markers that you can enable, on mass, on the scrollbar under Tools | Options | Text Editor | {Language} | Scroll Bars | Show annotations over vertical scroll bar.

(Extensions can further extend this, eg. Productivity Power Tool's [Match Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MatchMargin) adds indicators for search.)

VS 2015 docs for this are easily [found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237345.aspx).

Comment: Is there any way to turn off just the grey dots? They turn off if I uncheck "marks", but that also turns off many other useful dots of other colours.