# Meaning of gray colored marks in enhanced scrollbar in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, scrollbar

I want to just know, what is meaning of gray marks in scrollbar in Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

Can I only turn off showing this marks in visual studio scrollbar?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803927/grey-dot-on-scrollbar

Comment: Thx, I did not find this post when i created this question. Sorry